# Consulta SQL Server no funciona, el parametro que utilizo para activarla esta en SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android-studio, sql-server

```
public class ResumenTotal extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    private ArrayList<ClaseResumen> array1;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resumen_total);

        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.srlContainer1);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Credenciales", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        boolean loguedo = preferences.getBoolean("Logeado",false);


        if(loguedo){
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            recyclerView1=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
            recyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);


            array1 = new ArrayList<ClaseResumen>();

            int iduser = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("IdUser",""));
            String fecha = preferences.getString("Fecha", "");
            try{
                Connection con;
                String un, contrasenha, db;
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server/BD";
                un = "user";
                contrasenha = "password";
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(db, un, contrasenha);  //Connection Object

                if (con != null) {
                    String query = "SELECT COUNT(t1.IdVenta), t2.NomDestino, t1.HoraSalida, SUM(t1.Monto) , t1.FechaViaje FROM SGP_Vnt_Venta t1 INNER JOIN SGP_Mant_Destino t2 ON t2.IdDestino = t1.IdDestino WHERE t1.IdUsuario = 136 AND t1.FechaViaje = '01-10-2017' AND t1.Anulado = 0 GROUP BY t1.IdDestino, t1.HoraSalida, t2.NomDestino, t1.FechaViaje";
                    //String query = "SELECT COUNT(t1.IdVenta), t2.NomDestino, t1.HoraSalida, SUM(t1.Monto) FROM SGP_Vnt_Venta t1 INNER JOIN SGP_Mant_Destino t2 ON t2.IdDestino = t1.IdDestino WHERE t1.IdUsuario = "+iduser+" AND t1.FechaViaje = '"+fecha+"' AND t1.Anulado = 0 GROUP BY t1.IdDestino, t1.HoraSalida, t2.NomDestino";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Log.d("RS",rs.getString(2));
                        array1.add(new ClaseResumen(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5)));
                        //Toast.makeText(ResumenTotal.this,rs.getString(1)+ rs.getString(2)+ rs.getString(3)+ rs.getString(4)+ rs.getString(5) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if (rs == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(ResumenTotal.this, "Error al Cargar Datos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ResumenTotal.this, "Revise Conexión a Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.e("ErrorConexion",e.getMessage());
            }
            recyclerView1.setAdapter(new Adaptador1(array1));
            recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }else{
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(ResumenTotal.this,MainActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Credenciales", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int iduser = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("IdUser",""));
                String fecha = preferences.getString("Fecha", "");
                SyncData syncData = new SyncData();
                syncData.execute("");
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```